# How do I change the background color with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Anyone know a simple method to swap the background color of a webpage using JavaScript?

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Modify the JavaScript property `document.body.style.background`.

For example:

```
function changeBackground(color) {
   document.body.style.background = color;
}

window.addEventListener("load",function() { changeBackground('red') });
```

Note: this does depend a bit on how your page is put together, for example if you're using a DIV container with a different background colour you will need to modify the background colour of that instead of the document body.

Answer (score 82):

You don't need AJAX for this, just some plain java script setting the background-color property of the body element, like this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
```

If you want to do it as if it was initiated by the server, you would have to poll the server and then change the color accordingly.

Comment: For answering literally: the question was about changing the color of the background, not all of the background.

Comment: This didn't work for me unless I put just "background" instead of "backgroundColor"

Answer (score 21):

I agree with the previous poster that changing the color by `className` is a prettier approach. My argument however is that a `className` can be regarded as a definition of "why you want the background to be this or that color."

For instance, making it red is not just because you want it red, but because you'd want to inform users of an error. As such, setting the className `AnErrorHasOccured` on the body would be my preferred implementation.

In css

```
body.AnErrorHasOccured
{
  background: #f00;
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
document.body.className = "AnErrorHasOccured";
```

This leaves you the options of styling more elements according to this `className`. And as such, by setting a `className` you kind of give the page a certain state.

Answer (score 12):

AJAX is getting data from the server using Javascript and XML in an asynchronous fashion. Unless you want to download the colour code from the server, that's not what you're really aiming for!

But otherwise you can set the CSS background with Javascript. If you're using a framework like jQuery, it'll be something like this:

```
$('body').css('background', '#ccc');
```

Otherwise, this should work:

```
document.body.style.background = "#ccc";
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do it in following ways
**STEP 1**

```
   var imageUrl= "URL OF THE IMAGE HERE";
   var BackgroundColor="RED"; // what ever color you want
```

For changing background of **BODY**

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage=imageUrl  //changing bg image
document.body.style.backgroundColor=BackgroundColor //changing bg color
```

**To change an element with ID**

```
document.getElementById("ElementId").style.backgroundImage=imageUrl
document.getElementById("ElementId").style.backgroundColor=BackgroundColor
```

**for elements with same class**

```
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ClassName")
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].style.background=imageUrl;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't really class this as "AJAX". Anyway, something like following should do the trick:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
```

Answer (score 5):

Css approach:

If you want to see continuous colour, use this code:

```
body{
    background-color:black;
    animation: image 10s infinite alternate;
    animation:image 10s infinite alternate;
    animation:image 10s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes image{
    0%{
background-color:blue;
}
25%/{
    background-color:red;
}
50%{
    background-color:green;
}
75%{

    background-color:pink;
}
100%{
    background-color:yellow;
    }
  }
```

If you want to see it faster or slower, change 10 second to 5 second etc.

Comment: I voted up because I like this answer. Even though it doesn't technically answer the OP question of using Javascript, it does solve the problem, in a nice way. If the page is using JS to do other document mods as well, then it would make sense to also do this in JS, but if this is the only sort of animation being done, then the CSS is a nicer approach over JS.

Answer (score 4):

You can change background of a page by simply using:

```
document.body.style.background = #000000; //I used black as color code
```

However the below script will change the background of the page after every 3 seconds using setTimeout() function:

```
$(function() {
            var colors = ["#0099cc","#c0c0c0","#587b2e","#990000","#000000","#1C8200","#987baa","#981890","#AA8971","#1987FC","#99081E"];

            setInterval(function() { 
                var bodybgarrayno = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
                var selectedcolor = colors[bodybgarrayno];
                $("body").css("background",selectedcolor);
            }, 3000);
        })
```

[**READ MORE**](http://codeforbrowser.com/blog/changing-background-color-using-javascript-and-jquery/)
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/gJWFR/1/)

Comment: You need quotes on that number though

Answer (score 4):

## Here are 2 ways to Change Background Color Using Javascript

1. To change background color with javascript you can apply
   **`style.background`** or **`style.backgroundColor`** on the element you want to change background for.

   The below example changes the background color of the body when you
   click an element using `style.background` property.

```js
function pink(){ document.body.style.background = "pink"; }
function sky(){ document.body.style.background = "skyblue"; }
```

```html
<p onclick="pink()" style="padding:10px;background:pink">Pink</p>
<p onclick="sky()" style="padding:10px;background:skyblue">Sky</p>
```

---

2. Another approach could be by adding a CSS class using
   javascript
   that gives a background to the element it is attached.

   You can see more ways to add class using javascript but here you can
   simply use `classList.add()` property.

   ```js
       function addClass(yourClass){
           document.body.classList.remove("sky", "pink");
           document.body.classList.add(yourClass);
       }
   ```

   ```css
       .pink {
           background: pink;
       }

       .sky {
           background: skyblue;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <p onclick="addClass('pink')" style="padding:10px;background:pink">Pink</p>
       <p onclick="addClass('sky')" style="padding:10px;background:skyblue">Sky</p>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to see the use of a css class here. It avoids having hard to read colors / hex codes in javascript.

```
document.body.className = className;
```

Answer (score 3):

if you wish to use a button or some other event, just use this in JS:

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this script element to your body element, changing the color as desired:

```html
<body>
  <p>Hello, World!</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";  // red
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will change the background color according to the choice of user selected from the drop-down menu:

```js
function changeBG() {
  var selectedBGColor = document.getElementById("bgchoice").value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = selectedBGColor;
}
```

```html
<select id="bgchoice" onchange="changeBG()">
    <option></option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="ivory">Ivory</option>
    <option value="pink">Pink</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you wish to specify the background color value in rgb notation then try

```
document.getElementById("yourid").style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${a}, ${b}, ${c})`;
```

where a,b,c are the color values

Example:

```
document.getElementById("yourid").style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(224,224,224)';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select name="" id="select" onClick="hello();">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option style="background-color: #CD5C5C;">#CD5C5C</option>
    <option style="background-color: #F08080;">#F08080</option>
    <option style="background-color: #FA8072;">#FA8072</option>
    <option style="background-color: #E9967A;">#E9967A</option>
    <option style="background-color: #FFA07A;">#FFA07A</option>
</select>
<script>
function hello(){
let d = document.getElementById("select");
let text = d.options[d.selectedIndex].value;
document.body.style.backgroundColor=text;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's your explanation and moreover, how is this any different from the other answers?

Answer (score 1):

so you can done very easily by just calling a function like

```
 function changeBg()
    {
      document.body.style.color.backgroundColor="#ffffff";

    }
```

Comment: That doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

But you would want to configure the body color before the `<body>` element exists. That way it has the right color from the get go.

```
<script>
    var myColor = "#AAAAAA";
    document.write('\
        <style>\
            body{\
                background-color: '+myColor+';\
            }\
        </style>\
    ');
</script>
```

This you can put in the `<head>` of the document or in your js file.

Here is a nice color to play with.

```
var myColor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following code:

```
<div id="example" onClick="colorize()">Click on this text to change the
background color</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function colorize() {
var element = document.getElementById("example");
element.style.backgroundColor='#800';
element.style.color='white';
element.style.textAlign='center';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change background of a page by simply using:

```
function changeBodyBg(color){
    document.body.style.background = color;
}
```

Read more @ [Changing the Background Color](http://www.jquerypot.com/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-web-page-dynamically-in-javascript/)

Answer (score -1):

It can be achieved using

```js
document.body.style.color.backgroundColor = "#000000";
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work.

Comment: It should be without that "color" part:
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";

Answer (score -5):

```
 <p id="p1">Hello, Moazzam!</p>
 <p >Hello, Moazzam!</p>
 <p >Hello, Moazzam!</p>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById("p1").style.color= "#ff0000";  // red
 </script>
```

Comment: This does not answer question. This will change the color, not the background color.