# Change the color of innerText according to the input value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, innertext

Below is a sample code for changing color on InnerText by a value in an input text.

The output looks like this. The color doesn't change

[image]

```js
function validate() {
  var msg;
  var result;
  if (document.myForm.userPass.value.length > 5) {
    msg = "good";
    result = msg.fontcolor("green");
  } else {
    msg = "poor";
    result = msg.fontcolor("red");
  }
  document.getElementById('mylocation').innerText = result;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="password" value="" name="userPass" onkeyup="validate()"> Strength:
  <span id="mylocation">no strength</span>
</form>
```

The answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727735/changing-text-colour-or-background-depending-on-value-of-input-field) is not the one I needed.

Comment: If you change `.innerText` to `.innerHTML` it will add your string as HTML not text

Comment: Create a span, set msg as its innertext, set span font color using the style API (<font> is deprecated for more than 10 years!), and set the span as the mylocation inner HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the font tag is not used by HTML5, the old `fontcolor` method will not work in browsers.

So I tried the below code.

```js
function validate() {
  var msg;

  if (document.myForm.userPass.value.length > 5) {
    document.getElementById('mylocation').style.color = "green";
    msg = "good";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('mylocation').style.color = "red";
    msg = "poor";
  }
  document.getElementById('mylocation').innerText = msg;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="password" value="" name="userPass" onkeyup="validate()"> Strength:
  <span id="mylocation">no strength</span>
</form>
<hr/>
```