# javascript Change page background color with button

Tags: javascript, button, background-color

I am trying to figure out how to do code for changing the background color of a page with a button

so basically I have the code for a button written out and its function but im having trouble figuring out what code to use to make the button change the color of the entire page

```
<script>
    function changeColor()
    {

    };
    function changeText()
    {
        alert ("change text in this part");
    };
    function sendMsg()
    {
        alert ("change msg content here");
    }
</script>
```

```
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to my program!</h1>
        <button onclick="changeColor()">Color</button>
        <button onclick="changeText()">Text</button> </br>
            <p>Can I ask you something Ive always wanted to ask the real Batman?</p> </br>
                 <input type="text" name="">
</body>
```

Comment: You can get answer on internet via search engine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript

Comment: thank you so much ive been searching for 45 minutes and every search has brought me how to change the color of a button and not the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  document.body.style.background = color;
```

There's not much more to it, it's as simple as that!

Comment: thanks very much, I had that code before but every time I tried it wouldnt execute properly, i finally figured it out tho thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Try out this code my dear     :

```
<FORM> 
<INPUT type="button" value="Change to Yellow!" name="button3" onClick="document.bgColor='yellow'"> <br> 
<INPUT type="button" value="Change to Red!" name="button4" onClick="document.bgColor='red'"> <br> 
<INPUT type="button" value="Change back!" name="button5" onClick="document.bgColor='white'"> </FORM>
```