# Change background color dynamically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my css a background-color is defined set as white, but I want to change color dynamically body of page.

How do you do that? my CSS file:

```
body {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

my javascript  code :

```
function init() 
{
    document.body.style.zoom="90%";
    document.body.color="white";
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `document.body.style.color="white"` , `document.body.style.backgroundColor="black" ` ?

Comment: document.body.color is the same as color in css, it applies to text color, not background color.

Comment: Bookmark this [link](http://www.sitestepper.be/en/css-properties-to-javascript-properties-reference-list.htm) . It'll be very helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.body.style.background = 'yourColor';
```

[How do I change the background color with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

For changing the style you need to access the [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.style) property, and the property of `background-color` is `backgroundColor`

```
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="white"
```