# changing css using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i tried to change the css style of a division using javascript.
here is Css

```
<style>
#box
{
height:200px;
width:200px;
background:#c0c0c0;
}
</style>
```

Here is javascript code

```
<script>
function fun()
{
setInterval(function(){fun1()},3000);
}

function fun1()
{
var x = document.getElementById("box");
x.style.backgroundColor="red";
} 
</script>
```

and within HTML body

```
<div id="box"></div>
<br>
<button type="button" onClick="fun();">Click here </button>
```

why isn't the color of the div being changed even after clicking the button?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript

Comment: Does write the `fun1()` instead of `function fun1()` works?

Comment: Do you declare `fun1` before button in `document`?

Comment: Here is a working example.. http://jsfiddle.net/dnDEN/

Comment: Did you actually look at the console and see the errors?

Comment: @epascarello i looked up at the console and the error shown was:- Uncaught TypeError: Property 'backgroundColor' of object #<CSSStyleDeclaration> is not a function

Comment: ANd that is your exact code above? It sounds like your code is `x.style.backgroundColor("red");`

Comment: @epascarello Thank you!! there was some answer here before to change my code to ...backgroundColor("red") and i did try that and completely forgot. It should be ..backgroundColor="red". Thank you once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in your console you would have seen you got some errors.

You should define a function as:

```
function fun(){ 
    // ...
}
```

instead of just

```
fun() {
    // .. 
}
```

So it should be :

```
function fun() {
    setInterval(fun1,3000);
}

function fun1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("box");
    x.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnDEN/2/) (Thanks skmasq)

Comment: @putvande thank you! but still it is not working. i looked it in the console and the error shown is :- Uncaught TypeError: Property 'backgroundColor' of object #<CSSStyleDeclaration> is not a function

Comment: Is your HTML exactly the same as in your question? If you see the Fiddle it put in my answer you see it works just fine.