# Change css background color in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have done an append using the following code, where `menuElement` is a id of a div and
`appendStr ="<span class="bubbleClass"></span>";`

```
$(menuElement).append(appendStr);
```

However, when i try `$(menuElement+ ".bubbleClass").css("background-color", "red");` it doesnt work.

I want the specific div id stored in  menuElement variable to be reflected.

Comment: found this question, basically the same question i think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript

Comment: @nCore Completely different question, because this issue is about selecting the right element, not changing its colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have dynamically added the item to the DOM, you need to use `.find()` to access it:

```
$(menuElement).append(appendStr).find('.bubbleClass').css({
    backgroundColor:'red',
    display:'inline'
});
```

That is an example based on the limited code you provided, but the use of `.find()` is the key.

Edited to include the `display` CSS you said you needed to add as well.

Comment: Thank you it worked i have to add display:inline style as well

Comment: updated my answer to include the `display` CSS setting as well. and glad it worked out, but if my answer helped please apply the checkmark. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is failing is because your selector looks like this: `#someID.bubbleClass`

In other words, it's looking for the `bubbleClass` class name on the `menuElement` itself, *not* on its children.

Add a space before the `.` and it should work just fine.

Comment: I have added a space and tried it.. it still doesnt work

Comment: Right now your `bubbleClass` has no content... so you can't see its result. Try putting some text in the element.

Answer (score 0):

menuElement should be a jQuery selector like `"#menuElement"` because it's wrapped inside the jQuery object.

> $("#menuElement + .bubbleClass").css("background-color","red");

Comment: Yes i had the menuElement variable to hold a string value which is actually a id of a element for example menuElement="#message". @PlantTheIdea user's solution worked for me.