# creating div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to create div using javascript, but struck up at one point. Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
    mydiv.id = "div1";
    mydiv.style.height = "200px";
    mydiv.style.width = "200px";
    mydiv.style.background-color = "red";

    document.body.appendChild(mydiv);
```

Your help is highly obliged.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the background color with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

`background-color` is an invalid identifier in JavaScript. You can use `backgroundColor` instead.

```
mydiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Any CSS property with a dash in it is done in camelCase on the `style` object. So `backgroundColor`, `marginLeft`, etc. The *values* you assign are strings, so this doesn't apply to them, just the property names.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `mydiv.style.backgroundColor`