# Select child element

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if this is the correct term (child element) but I have CSS I need to change with JavaScript. How do I make this text area field visible?

```
#desc {
 display = 'none';
}

#desc textarea {
     display: none;
     background-color: red;
}


<div id='desc'>
     <textarea> </textarea>
</div>

var x = document.getElementById('desc').style.display = 'block';
var t = document.getElementById('textarea').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the background color with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript)

Comment: `#Desc textarea` should be `#desc textarea` and `document.getElementById('textarea')` won't work because no element has the ID of `textarea`. And `display = 'none';` should be `display:none;`

Comment: `document.querySelector('#desc textarea').style....`

Comment: The "var t" line doesn't seem to work, I can make the #desc div visible but i CANNOT get the text area to be visible as well because it is INSIDE the desc div and the CSS property (dec -> textarea) is specifically set to 'none' I cannot figure out how in JAVASCRIPT to access that text area property.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
document.getElementById('desc').style = 'display:block';
document.getElementByTagName('textarea')[0].style = 'display:block';
```

Or,

`document.querySelector('#desc textarea').style = 'display:block;'1`

<sup><sup>1</sup> [Credits to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801272/select-child-element#comment45876367_28801272) [@adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo)</sup>