# how to set dynamic colour using css

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to set dynamic `background colour` using `CSS`.

For example if you go to [this link](http://iavinash.com/questions/) you will see the background colour of the `Ask a question` button is `#5CB85`C but my theme colour is `#CD2122`. What is want is Background colour of `Ask a question` should be dependant on my theme colour. So if I change the theme colour to `Red`, `Blue` or anything button colour should also be changed accordingly.

Hope I was able to explain it clearly.

Thanks
Avinash

Comment: Duplicity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

you have to made a css for this two different css like blue.css n red.css when your theme color red than call red.css .. according to theme change css..

Comment: Thanks.. but i cannot create so many css... The background color variation could be infinite.