# How do you change the background color of an webpage with JS?

Tags: html

I have this script that here that I'll program later to continously change the background color, but for some reason it does not work at all. It's not throwing any errors either

```
<html>
<body id = "BGCOLOR" bgcolor = rgb(0,0,0); >
<script>
function ChangeColor(){
    document.getElementById("BGCOLOR").bgcolor = "rgb(0,50,0)";
}
ChangeColor();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the background color with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

for more refrence check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp

Answer (score 0):

friend try this code

```
 <html>
    <body id = "BGCOLOR" bgcolor = rgb(0,0,0); >
    <script>
    function ChangeColor(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,50,0)";
    }
    ChangeColor();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```