# dynamically change style of html tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the html tag dynamically in JavaScript.

I have tried using

```
document.getElementById("html").setAttribute("style", "background: #000000")
```

but received the following error:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null*

How would I go about doing so?

**CSS**

```
html {
   background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: what is the error you got ?

Comment: is the id of your element "html" or are you trying to access the html tag?

Comment: @user2181397 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: @GraveyardQueen i am trying to access the html tag

Comment: You need to add more detail here. If you receive an error, always include the error in your question. If you're selecting something from the DOM, it may be useful to see the element you're selecting. @GraveyardQueen's question could have been avoided by doing so. 

Better questions help us help you get answers.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#000000";`
```

Although it is possible to add the style attribute with a value to an element with setAttribute method, it is recommended that you use properties of the Style object instead for inline styling, because this will not overwrite other CSS properties that may be specified in the style attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.background = "#000000";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referring the the html tag rather than an element in the html body,
the getElementByID requires a string that is an element id.
For example

```
<p id="myID">text</p>
```

then you cound do

```
document.getElementByID('myID').setAttribute('style', 'background: red');
```

probably first put the element into a variable but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have used document.getElementById to find the Html Tag.

You have to use

```
document.getElementsByTagName
```

to locate an element By tag Name

For Reference:
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp)

Comment: He makes no mention of using jQuery.

Comment: I am just expressing the simplicity of jQuery in this process.

Comment: I edited it out as it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: Thanks for making the change :)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to style the `html` element; but I'm willing to bet that it's *not* marked up like so:

`<html id="html">`

...so your selector won't work.

You're probably needing to use this instead (from [How do I change the background color with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript)):

`document.body.style.background = '#000000'`

(Note: targets the `body` element.)

Comment: @jnara be sure to update his answer and accept it. Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly what you wanted (as per the CSS in your question):

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("background","#000000");
```