# Uncaught ReferenceError: (function) darkmode is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make a lyrics site with a dark mode but the dark mode button 
just causes errors

I've tried finding solutions online but most of them say to move the script inside of the body tag but my script is already in the body

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lyrics Page</title>
</head>
<style>
#bgr {
  background-color: white;
}
#lyrics {
   color:black; 
}
#songtitle {
   color: black; 
   text-align:center;
}
</style>
<body id=bgr>
    <script>
            function darkmode() {
              document.getElementById("bgr").style.background-color = "black"; 
              document.getElementById("songtitle").style.color = "grey";
              document.getElementById("lyrics").style.color = "grey";        
            }
            </script>
    <button type="button" onclick="darkmode()">Dark Mode</button>
<h1 id=songtitle>song</h1>
<h2 id=songtitle>artist</h2>
<br>
<center id=lyrics>paragraph 1</center>
<br>
<center id=lyrics>paragraph 2</center>
<br>
<center id=lyrics>paragraph 3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the background color with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript)

Comment: Change `style.background-color` to `style.background`. You can't have a dash in a JavaScript property name. It gives a syntax error.

Comment: Also `<DOCTYPE! html>` should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`. This is not related to your issue, but it is invalid HTML otherwise.

Comment: I also just noticed that you have multiple elements with the same `id`. That is not allowed, `id`s should be unique in the document. (Now your `getElementById` will only match the first.) Try to use a `class` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `document.getElementById("bgr").style.background-color = "black";` part. When setting css properties in JavaScript you should use camelCase. So if you change:

```
document.getElementById("bgr").style.background-color = "black";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("bgr").style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your javascript code. It is not `background-color`, it is `backgroundColor`.

Your code working:

```js
function darkmode() {
    document.getElementById("bgr").style.backgroundColor = "black"; 
    document.getElementById("songtitle").style.color = "grey";
    document.getElementById("lyrics").style.color = "grey";        
}
```

```css
#bgr {
  background-color: white;
}
#lyrics {
   color:black; 
}
#songtitle {
   color: black; 
   text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lyrics Page</title>
</head>
<body id="bgr">
    
    <button type="button" onclick="darkmode()">Dark Mode</button>
<h1 id="songtitle">song</h1>
<h2 id="songtitle">artist</h2>
<br>
<center id="lyrics">paragraph 1</center>
<br>
<center id="lyrics">paragraph 2</center>
<br>
<center id="lyrics">paragraph 3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the first line of your darkmode function.

```
    'document.getElementById("bgr").style.background-color = "black";`
```

you need to change background-color to backgroundColor

---

Javascript doesn't see the hyphen as a part of the name, but instead subtraction. Resulting in an error because you are trying to set an expression equal to "black", not a variable like you intended.