# How to change background-color using input type=color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change background-color using input type=color? If i select blue the background-color is blue, if I select red the background color is red.

Comment: Use the [`input` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).

Comment: [How do I change the background color with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197748/14032355)

Answer (score 2):

Listen for the `input` event and assign the value of the input to the `backgroundColor` property of the body style:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
})
```

```html
<input type="color">
```